# Angular 2 switching outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a `ParentComponent` that contains `ChildAComponent` and `ChildBComponent`, and I want the following behavior :

1. When navigating to `"/parent"`, navigate to `"/parent/child-A"`

   - i.e load `ChildAComponent` in `outletA`
2. When clicking `X` link, navigate to corresponding `"/parent/child-(X)"`

   - i.e load `Child(X)Component` in `outlet(X)` **and close `outlet(Y)` if opened**.

I came up with the solution of making **two auxiliaries routes** :

My `parent.component.html` :

```
<router-outlet name="outletA"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="outletB"></router-outlet>
<a routerLink="[{ outlets: { outletA: ['childA'], outletB: null } }]">Child A</a>
<a routerLink="[{ outlets: { outletB: ['childB'], outletA: null } }]">Child B</a>
```

And my `app.routing.ts` :

```
const routes: Routes = [
    path: '/parent',
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [
        {                          // <--- this redirect
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'child-A',
            outlet: 'outletA'
        },
        {
            path: 'child-A',
            component: ChildAComponent,
            outlet: 'outletA'  
        },
        {
            path: 'child-B',
            component: ChildBComponent,
            outlet: 'outletB'  
        }
    ]
]
```

The **problem** is :

- With the redirect, router binding is not working (outlet A is always displayed)
- Without the redirect, binding is working, but I cannot have the (1) behavior, the default route from parent to child A.

I thought about using primary and auxiliary routes instead of two auxiliaries (one outlet and one named outlet) but as far as I know, it's not possible to close an outlet without name.

Any advice is very welcome.

Comment: Do you need multiple outlets for this? It seems that you want to redirect default to child-a and if clicking on different route you want to go to that named component? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. In my particular case, the outlets are at different location on the page, so I had no choice to have two outlets